# Is there any way to have a villager trade materials for armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I forgot my crafting table back at my house, and I have no other crafting table.  I want to craft some iron armor and I have a lot of ingots.
I couldn't find any trees since I ended up in a desert. I found a village, but there was no Library, where there's a spare crafting table. I only found a Blacksmith. I looked inside the chest to find some iron ingots.  I wanted to trade the Blacksmith villager for some armor, but it costs emeralds and I don't have any. There were some farms, but there were no farmer villagers that will accept wheat for emeralds.
I wish I can trade the Blacksmith villager the iron ingots in return for a piece of iron armor.

Is there any way I can trade my iron ingots to the Blacksmith in return for a piece of armor? I am aware there is no way to do it natively, but is there a command or mod solution available somehow?

Comment: Go find a villager.

Comment: I think you've gotten an answer (may not be what you're looking for), and you were asking for a mod, we've provided you a solution that doesn't require one.

Comment: I'm currently working on a question that doesn't mention "is there a mod", directly. per [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-an-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing#question).

Comment: Sorry guys, my forgiveness. Reopening this question just changed my life. I won't go to Gamefaqs again [but they are also a reliable source].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 2):

## There are 4 solutions to your problem.

1. Use MCEdit and some filters to create custom villager.
2. Use NBTEdit(in game) or NBTExplorer (not in game) to modify tags of the villager
3. Use Custom NPC's and create custom villager that you can customize trades with
4. Or open your game to LAN and make sure to turn on cheats. Then go to gamemode 1, take some pieces of armor and ditch your ingots to little "X" icon on the right down corner of the survival inventory.