# How can I summon a named Villager that trades items with a colored name and lore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create Villagers that buy  and sell items with a specific name and lore.

I need a Villager named "Seller" (Without the quotation marks).

"Seller" will buy a Gold Nugget named "&e&lMoney" containing a lore that says "&6M.H.A. &eCurrency" (Again, no quotation marks).

"Seller" will sell a Cookie named "&6M.H.A. &eCookie" containing a lore that says "&eEat &eMe!" (For the last time, no quotation marks).

Please note that I need all of this in Vanilla. Thank you in advance to anyone that helps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're more likely to get answers if you make an attempt to solve the problem and ask about parts that aren't working, rather than asking us to create the entire thing for you.

Comment: I've used generators, but none of them have custom item name and lore editors. I don't know a lot about command blocks too, so that's why I need your guys' help.

Comment: `/give @p minecraft:cookie 1 0 {display:{Lore:["Bar"],Name:"Foo"}}` would give you a named cookie. Now you can solve the puzzle with the villager yourself. :)

Comment: what about the colored name?

Comment: I know how to add lores and name items, I need help putting those items so that the villager sells it.

Comment: Which generator do you use? I use [mcstacker](https://mcstacker.net/) for the things I don't know, and it has custom item names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 1):

`/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {CareerLevel:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"&e&lMoney",Lore:["&6M.H.A. &eCurrency"]}}},sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"&6M.H.A. &eCookie",Lore:["&eEat &eMe!"]}}}}]}}` would do just that.

`/summon villager ~ ~ ~`: Summons a villager at the current location

`CareerLevel:1`: The current level of the villager's trading options. I would recommend setting this high to avoid the villager putting its own trades up.

`Offers:{Recipes:[`: A list of all the trades made by the villager. All trades must be put in separate `{}`s

`buy:`, `buyB`: The two items in the front of the trade. These must have an item id (`id:"minecraft:item"`) and a count (`Count:1b`). to set required tags for the item, add `tag:` and put NBT data in `{}`s.

`sell:`: The item the villager is selling. This must also have an item id and a count, with an optional data tag.