# How can I give villagers custom trade items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command that gives a villager spawn egg with custom trades I want every item in the game to be in the villager thanks

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:villager”},/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:villager”},{Profession:1,CustomName:"Shadow imperial funds",CustomNameVisible:1,Career:1,CareerLevel:42,CanPickUpLoot:0,PersistenceRequired:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,Invulnerable:1,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:"1f"},{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:99999}],Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:0},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"log",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"log",Count:64,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"log",Count:64,Damage:2},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"log",Count:64,Damage:3},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"bedrock",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"dirt",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:999999999,sell:{id:"gold_block",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999999,sell:{id:"emerald_block",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:99999999999,sell:{id:"barrier",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"sea_lantern",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"tnt",Count:64},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"log",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"stone",Count:1,Damage:6},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"stone",Count:1,Damage:2},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"stone",Count:1,Damage:4},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"sandstone",Count:1,Damage:2},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"sandstone",Count:1,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"sandstone",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"sand",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"lapis_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"obsidian",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"mossy_cobblestone",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"prismarine",Count:1,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"quartz_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"end_stone",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"glowstone",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"redstone_lamp",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"hay_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"coal_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"packed_ice",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"glass",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"snow_layer",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"log2",Count:1,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"gravel",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"experience_bottle",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"golden_apple",Count:1,Damage:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:2},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:3},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:4},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:5},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:6},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:7},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:8},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:9},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:10},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:11},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:12},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:13},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:14},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:15},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"brick_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"iron_block",Count:1},rewardExp:false}]}}}
```

Comment: cut this guy some slack I would not know

Comment: @Epb7304 Whether you would know or not is irrelevant; we expect users to show some level of effort in solving their own issues here.

Comment: I have tried yes  @frank I have a code put together if you would like to see it Ill add it to the question thanks

Comment: OK, so that's a start. Where did this come from? There seems to be many repeat items.

Comment: @frank I put together some of my knowledge with some online generators and thats what I was able to put together but it doesn't seem to work and I cant debug it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 0):

this command should do it with one trade:

```
give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"villager",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:
1,Count:1},sell:{id:2,Count:1}}]}}}
```

but you'll have to play around with the IDs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a generator, like Minecraft Tools. I would recommend trying something different, as this will take a long time.