# How do I summon specific villagers in Minecraft 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried using codes from Minecraft 1.13 to summon specific villagers, but it doesn't seem to work as I always get the same villager.
Is there such a command that works in Minecraft 1.14?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format

Comment: It always helps to show your work, in this case the commands you've tried already.  It shows that you've already tried to solve your own problem, which is something we like to see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to summon a villager with commands is by using online command generators. [Here](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/villager_trade.php) is a custom online villager generator for 1.14.

You can edit the offers, name, profession, and much more aspects of your villager.