# How do i summon custom villagers that sell custom prefilled chests

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was making a trading system on my minecraft server (e.x. 64 iron blocks = good armor) and i couldnt figure out how to make the villagers sell custom prefilled chests
if you want to do it for me i would love it!
Prefilled chest give command:

/give @p chest{display:{Name:"\"Iron Rank\""},BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:iron_helmet,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:respiration,lvl:3},{id:aqua_affinity,lvl:1},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:1,id:iron_chestplate,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:2,id:iron_leggings,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:3,id:iron_boots,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:feather_falling,lvl:3},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:depth_strider,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:4,id:iron_sword,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5},{id:knockback,lvl:2},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:2},{id:looting,lvl:3},{id:sweeping,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:5,id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:6,id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:silk_touch,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:7,id:iron_axe,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5},{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:8,id:iron_shovel,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:9,id:iron_shovel,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:silk_touch,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:10,id:iron_hoe,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}}]}} 1
sorry if its long but this is the command so if you could please put this into a villager trade i would love it!

Comment: "do it for me" is almost exactly the wording that I use when describing what this website is NOT for. Instead, we're here to help when you have a problem that you can't solve yourself, in a project that you do yourself. I recommend you to try it yourself with an easier example, like a villager trading for stone, then for an item with a custom tag and then for your gigantic chest thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the command in a command block because it's too long:

```
summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{level:5,profession:farmer,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:emerald,Count:10b},sell:{id:chest,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'"Iron Rank"'},BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:iron_helmet,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:respiration,lvl:3},{id:aqua_affinity,lvl:1},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:1,id:iron_chestplate,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:2,id:iron_leggings,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:3,id:iron_boots,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:feather_falling,lvl:3},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:depth_strider,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:4,id:iron_sword,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5},{id:knockback,lvl:2},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:2},{id:looting,lvl:3},{id:sweeping,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:5,id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:6,id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:silk_touch,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:7,id:iron_axe,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5},{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:8,id:iron_shovel,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:9,id:iron_shovel,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:silk_touch,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}},{Slot:10,id:iron_hoe,Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1}]}}]}}}}]}}
```

I set the price to 10 emeralds and the max uses to 10, which you can change. This command will summon a plains farmer level 5 villager but you can change the `VillagerData` to whatever you want (see [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Entity_data) for more information).

Formatted NBT:

```
{
  VillagerData: {
    level: 5,
    profession: farmer,
    type: plains
  },
  Offers: {
    Recipes: [{
      maxUses: 10,
      buy: {id: emerald, Count: 10b},
      sell: {
        id: chest,
        Count: 1b,
        tag: {
          display: {Name: '"Iron Rank"'},
          BlockEntityTag: {
            Items: [
              {
                Slot: 0,
                id: iron_helmet,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: protection, lvl: 4},
                    {id: respiration, lvl: 3},
                    {id: aqua_affinity,lvl: 1},
                    {id: thorns,lvl: 3},
                    {id: unbreaking,lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending,lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 1,
                id: iron_chestplate,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: protection, lvl: 4},
                    {id: thorns, lvl: 3},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 2,
                id: iron_leggings,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: protection, lvl: 4},
                    {id: thorns, lvl: 3},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 3,
                id: iron_boots,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: protection, lvl: 4},
                    {id: feather_falling, lvl: 3},
                    {id: thorns, lvl: 3},
                    {id: depth_strider, lvl: 3},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 4,
                id: iron_sword,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: sharpness, lvl: 5},
                    {id: knockback, lvl: 2},
                    {id: fire_aspect, lvl: 2},
                    {id: looting, lvl: 3},
                    {id: sweeping, lvl: 3},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 5,
                id: iron_pickaxe,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: efficiency, lvl: 5},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: fortune, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 6,
                id: iron_pickaxe,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: efficiency, lvl: 5},
                    {id: silk_touch, lvl: 1},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 7,
                id: iron_axe,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: sharpness, lvl: 5},
                    {id: efficiency, lvl: 5},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: fortune, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 8,
                id: iron_shovel,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: efficiency, lvl: 5},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: fortune, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 9,
                id: iron_shovel,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: efficiency, lvl: 5},
                    {id: silk_touch, lvl: 1},
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                Slot: 10,
                id: iron_hoe,
                Count: 1b,
                tag: {
                  Enchantments: [
                    {id: unbreaking, lvl: 3},
                    {id: mending, lvl: 1}
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```