# MC Java Villager commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help. Any Minecraft coders out here? Can you code a command for something like this? it is for, Minecraft Java 1.16.5 on Apex Hosting servers.

Request:

Code a summon command for a villager with the following trades:

1: 15 Emerald = 1 Mending book

2: 15 Emerald = 1 Unbreaking 3 book

3: 15 Emerald = 1 Protection 4 book

4: 15 Emerald = 1 Thorns 3 book

5: 15 Emerald = 1 Sharpness 4 book

6: 15 Emerald = 1 Efficiency 5 book

7: 10 Emerald = 1 Fortune 3 book

8: 5 Paper = 10 Emerald

9: 4 Emerald = 20 XP bottles

10: 2 Emerald = 10 books

Comment: this looks like 10 questions in one

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13507/4797)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/villager_trade.php).

You can fill out these fields to generate a villager with the exact trades you want.

Entering "Enchanted Book" into a field will open an extra tab where you can enter which exact enchant you want on said book.

If you are stuck when using it, they also have a youtube video up on the top of the page.

When you are done, place a command block in the world (I'm assuming you are admin) and paste the generated command in, and then turn the block on. You can then break the block if it's no longer needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This does help.

Comment: You're welcome, just please google things beforehand, when searching "Minecraft spawn villager with custom trades", this came up first thing in google.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I am on a limited Laptop right now. So some sites are blocked. Lol.