# How do I summon a custom villager with multiple custom trades?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I am trying to figure out how to summon a custom villager with multiple custom trades. Can you help me make a command?

I am trying to trade 4 emeralds for a pair of diamond boots with protection 1, 8 emeralds for a pair of diamond boots with protection, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Comment: What version are you in?

Comment: @ppery that assumes this is talking about Java edition

Comment: @Penguin If I'm not mistaken, this is an impossible NBT request on Bedrock Edition, and thus a duplicate of [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/185203). I believe that the correct procedure for questions that would be closed as a duplicate for both editions is to close as a duplicate of both questions. Also, you misspelled my username as "ppery" (2 p's) instead of "pppery" (3 p's), so I didn't get that notification.

Comment: @pppery if at least one person votes to close for that will it show both?

Comment: @Penguin Yes, as long as a majority of the votes are for some kind of duplicate (I can't see close votes since I have <3k rep)