# Is there a way to get my librarians back after they were just killed by zombies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have my own server running Minecraft version 1.17.

After hours of trying to get the best librarian trades, I have them all. However, just before going AFK, they where killed by a zombie. I killed the server, and logged out, but I was too late. All my librarians were killed.

Is there a way to get them back? Maybe something that will undo the last 20 deaths? All I found was a spawn villager command, but that does not seem to have a parameter for the book you want the librarian to sell.

Is there a way to get my librarians back after they were just killed by zombies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers)

Comment: Maybe consider this a learning experience and build better fortifications for your villages next time?

Comment: Alternatively, consider backing up frequently (which has the added bonus of protecting your worlds in the event of e.g. drive failure, flash flooding, house fire, power surge, zombie apocalypse, Armageddon).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The spawn villager command can be given additional parameters to modify the data of a Villager. I will not claim to be an expert in using such commands, but what I can do is link this [external tool](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/villager_trade.php) which will allow you to customize a villager and generate the resulting code to be input into a command block. Using this tool, you can customize your villagers to your hearts content, even being able to make them unkillable.