# Is there any way I can make villagers buy items from me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to role-play running a store inside a village. Is there any way I can set out some items for sale, and have villagers come buy them from me?

Comment: The edit has turned the question from an off-topic mod rec into either a duplicate of [How do I create a villager with custom trade offers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224866/how-do-i-create-a-villager-with-custom-trade-offers) or an insufficiently focused question. Not really much better.